# How to disable MDBootstrap's accordin with Angular

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

I have a question, if somebody knows how to disable option to click and collapse accordion from MDBootstrap. In their documentation I cant find a way to do this. Here is link: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b5/angular/components/accordion/

Does anbody have an idea, how to do this? Here is exmaple with code, so I that is reason why I am not writing any code in the question.

Emaple:

```
<mdb-accordion
          [multiple]="true"
>
  <mdb-accordion-item>
    <ng-template mdbAccordionItemHeader>Accordion Item #1</ng-template>
    <ng-template mdbAccordionItemBody>
     Accordion tab 1
    </ng-template>
  </mdb-accordion-item>

  <mdb-accordion-item>
    <ng-template mdbAccordionItemHeader>Accordion Item #2</ng-template>
    <ng-template mdbAccordionItemBody>
     Accordion tab 2
    </ng-template>
  </mdb-accordion-item>

  <mdb-accordion-item>
    <ng-template mdbAccordionItemHeader>Accordion Item #3</ng-template>
    <ng-template mdbAccordionItemBody>
      Accordion tab 3
    </ng-template>
  </mdb-accordion-item>
</mdb-accordion>
```

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: The questions on SO should have [mre]

Comment: No need for stackblitz, its presence is not [mre]. The question post should have the code that can be reproduced and tested/debugged. Demo is the bonus but not requirement

Comment: I did this, but as I said MDBootstrap is not free so it can't reallly be reproduced if someone didn't puchase it. Thats the reason why I pasted a link with documentation..
I would be very happy if you could help me if there is possible to disable function to click on accordion..

Answer (score 1):

I open all panels using `this.accordion.expandAll();` and then pereventing `panelChange` event with `event.preventDefault()`  to stop them from being collapsed afterwards.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api#NgbPanelChangeEvent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

```html
<ngb-accordion
  #acc="ngbAccordion"
  activeIds="ngb-panel-0"
  (panelChange)="onPanelChange($event)">
  <ngb-panel #panel title="Simple">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
      richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel>
    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
      <span>&#9733; <b>Fancy</b> title &#9733;</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
      richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel title="Something">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
      richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-accordion-basic',
  templateUrl: './accordion-basic.html',
})
export class NgbdAccordionBasic implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('acc') accordion: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.accordion.expandAll();
  }

  onPanelChange(event: any) {
    if (event?.nextState === false) {
      console.log('no change allowed!');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zakst1?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccordion-basic.html

### MD BOOTSTRAP

> Omit the `data-mdb-parent` attribute on each `.accordion-collapse` to make accordion items stay open when another item is opened.

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/components/accordion/#section-always-open

Comment: I tried to duplicate but without success. It seems like with MDBootstrap I can't use (panelChange).. It doesn't do anything, not even access the function (tried with console.log())... I am using this package: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b5/angular/components/accordion/

Comment: Follow installation guides: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#installation `ng-bootstrap` is bootstrap for Angular. However if indeed you have to use MD then the API is slightly different and you have to refactor. https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b5/angular/components/accordion/#docsTabsAPI

Sorry, it's my mistake for not noticing you were talking about MD bootstrap.

Comment: Using MDB is a must for me sadly.  In  the API there is not a single line about how to disable accordion :S I am really lost with this.

Comment: Just copy paste this example. https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/components/accordion/#section-always-open

Comment: Yes, but as i wrote in question. I need to make a specific tab disabled. So if some statement is true, user can't click on dropdown item and on other items he can